# Test Rotating Device in AVD

Tags: android

I'm using AVD to test the app. When I press CTRL-F12, the emulator window rotated, but the screen in it doesn't. It's still in Potrait mode. I can't still test the roration behavior. I have checked in the System Setting in the emulator system, the Auto Rotate Screen is on.

Comment: 2.2 and 4.0.4 emulators work well. 2.3 doesn't. 3.x, if I remember well, also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Many apps, including many (most?) phone launchers, won't switch to landscape mode on device rotation. Most tablet launchers do rotate, so try a tablet AVD.

If it's your own app that's not rotating, make sure you don't have `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` specified in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: I'm using my own developed app. Even using tablet AVD, I face the same problem. And there's no screen orientation setting in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

change the orientation of activity in AndroidMainifest file may be the orientation of your activity is portrait